# Rotating an point with an tilted Coordinate System in 3d

Tags: c#, math, 3d, rotation, coordinates

I try to convert an given point in the normal coordinate system, to an tilted coordinate system.

What i have given:
The point (2;0;0) in the "normal coordinate system"

With the old coordinate system:

[X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZBoY.png)

X3;Y3;Z3 the vectors for the local z axis you get from the vector product of x vector (1) and y vector (2)

The tilted coordinate system is at 
[45 degree tilted coord sys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qITBV.png)
and 
X3: 0
Y3: 1
Z3: 0
The coord sys is tilted 45°, but i don´t have that info.
[a picture about the tilted coord sys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIk1G.png)

I want to know where the point (2;0;0) getting moved to.

There are many sources about 2D tilting, but not about 3D. I am trying to calculate it "by hand" but also try to write an c# programm about it. So if you just can answer me with an c# function you can do it.

I tried to work with euler angles and looked at quaternions, but i couldn´t get the right calculations with the calculator. And the fact that i don´t have the angle, just the vectors of the new coordinate system is hard for me to imagine how to deal with it.

I think this formula can be useful for me, but i dont have the rotation angle to fill. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle

I hope you understood my question, otherwise feel free to ask and i try to explain it more/better.

Comment: In general, what you are trying to do is to perform a basis change. That is, you have two coordinate systems - each specified by three basis vectors pointing in the x-, y- and z-directions of the coordinate system. Now you want to convert a coordinate (2,0,0 in your case) to the other coordinate system. Trying to find a rotation matrix may be possible, but this is the hard and complicated way. Instead, the correct transformation matrix can be found directly by assembling a matrix from your tabulated X1;Y1;Z1...X3;Y3;Z3 values. Google for "change of basis matrix" and watch some of the tutorials

Comment: Ok, your solution is working on paper very well. I will now try to implement it in c#. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Thomas stated out, i had to use the change of basis matrix. The gauss elimination algo helped me there.